# Python Pandas DataFrame convert columns of each row to one single column as Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am trying to get the data of Pandas.DataFrame (df) into the shape (3,1) with each row being a Pandas.Series. 
When I run my code I keep getting NaN in every single cell instead of the Pandas.Series.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
s = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(len(df.index))) #creates desired shape

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row)
    s.iloc[index] = pd.Series(row)
s.head()
```

Comment: is there a specific reason you want each row to be a series object? This usually isn't good practive, can it be a list?

Comment: I need to convert time-series data to be able to use it in this tutorial: https://alan-turing-institute.github.io/sktime/examples/univariate_time_series_classification.html

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want

```
X_train = np.array(pd.Series(df.values.tolist())).reshape(3, 1)

print(X_train.shape)
(3, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set the location to a value. Instead consider creating a DataFrame as

```
s = pd.DataFrame(columns=['new_column']) # Empty Dataframe with 1 Column
```

Then you can append your rows with

```
s = s.append({'new_column': row}, ignore_index=True) # Add the Series as an Element
```